# Mounting SSD on Debian Bullseye

Tags: debian, mount, ssd, home, clonezilla

I'm trying to use a USB-port connected SSD (external SSD) for my Linux home directory, and am encountering several strange behaviors. I am using ssh to connect to the machine.
I'm running Debian from a USB stick (I tried installing the whole OS on the SSD directly but had issues there as well).

Under `/home`, After running `mount /dev/sda1 user`, and `cd user` I ran `dd` to test the write speed (`dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=64k count=16k conv=fdatasync`, but discovered
the write speed is only about 4MB/s. Meaning the SSD is *not* used for the directory. On that note, when using another ssh instance (because the one running dd is blocking) to check the file size (`du -sh test`) and it *does* show 1.0G, although `dd` is still running. Does it mean it actually does use the SSD (and thus finished writing to the file) and another issue is causing it to take longer?
When I tried running the same on a subdirectory (`/home/user/test_dir`), it did work and showed `632 MB/s`.

Another possibly strange thing is that running `lsblk -o name,rota` lists `sda1` as `ROTA 1`. Shouldn't it be `ROTA 0` since it's an SSD and not an HD?

What am I doing wrong? I looked online for explanation but could not find ones pertaining to my problems.

There's no user data on the OS installation or SSD, so formatting / resetting is not a problem and there's no need to backup anything. I'd like to have the SSD mounted on `/home` and have the increased speeds. I also don't have an issue (and actually prefer) to have the entire os running from the SSD. I tried duplicating the usb stick (with the Debian installation on it) to the SSD via "CloneZilla", but it didn't go through as well.

Finally, if my question is lacking focus / inappropriate for StackExchange, I'd appreciate if you could point me at a forum more suitable for these kinds of questions.

Comment: How is your SSD physically connected to the system? Is it NVMe on the motherboard, a SATA-connected SSD (and older systems may have SATA connectors with different maximum throughput), or is an USB connection involved? Or does the system contain an old and forgotten HDD you might have accidentally mounted instead of the SSD? Something is clearly wrong, but your question has so little hard data about your system that it's difficult to determine anything else. If your Debian is running some "live media with persistence", that might be making filesystem access less efficient than normal.

Comment: Also, if you just mounted the SSD without first `mkfs`:ing it to some native Linux filesystem, changes are it contains a NTFS filesystem, which on Debian Bullseye is accessed with FUSE-based NTFS-3g, which is... not exactly a high performance filesystem solution.

Comment: @telcoM I edited my question to add that my SSD is external. There's no other drive on it. It's a new motherboard. As for `mkfs`ing, I'm not sure but maybe I did forget to do that. Is there a chance that's the issue? Or is it just a small improvement?

Comment: The performance of ntfs-3g is quite poor even on direct-connected SATA or NVMe; it is clearly focused on providing compatibility, not performance. As the disk is empty, you might want to try your test with the disk unmounted, writing directly onto the partition: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda1 bs=64k count=16k conv=fdatasync`. Note that this **will destroy** any filesystem currently on `sda1` and will require running `mkfs` on it afterwards. I'd also ensure that the USB connection uses USB 3 instead of USB 2 speeds; the USB 3 contacts can be finicky sometimes.

Comment: @telcoM I tried writing directly to the partition as you asked and same. Now even 2.1 MB/s. I also tried changing the USB port (it was on a USB3 one, switched to USB2) and still (I couldn't understand from your answer, *should* USB 3 be used or rather USB2?). Could the SSD itself that's the root of the problem? I ordered it online for $20... Still odd because as mentioned it did work occasionally, and connecting it to a Windows machine didn't show any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, you said you got the SSD online for $20. That would be a suspiciously cheap price for even the cheapest new SATA SSD.

I suspect you got a fake SSD that claims to have a much larger capacity than it actually has: to defeat casual testing, it just reuses what it has over and over, so it will overwrite the oldest data it has - without any warning. That would explain your problems with Linux installation too.

For Linux, [there is a `f3` toolkit for detecting fake SSDs and USB sticks](https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/f3-usb-capacity-fake-usb-test-linux): on Debian, just `apt install f3` as root to get it. Then you could use `f3probe /dev/sda` while the SSD is unmounted for a quick test.

For a more thorough test, you could mount the (`mkfs`'d) SSD, and run `f3write /home/user` or wherever you mounted the flash drive, to fill it with test files, and then `f3read /home/user` to verify that the contents of all those files is still actually on the SSD and not overwritten by later files.

There are a number of tools for Windows for testing USB disks and SSDs for fake capacity too: the most well known are probably `h2testw` (thorough but slow) or `FakeFlashTest` (quick).

See: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/test-and-detect-fake-or-counterfeit-usb-flash-drives-bought-from-ebay-with-h2testw/

Comment: Yeah, I never built or ordered parts but now after I checked it does seem like the case. Thanks